# Solving Op amp Voltage output

Tags: operational-amplifier

With the following circuit:

[image]

There is a resistor (R2) in front of RL. So how would you find Vout?

I already know the formula for finding Vout (Vout = -(RF/R1) X Vin), but what do you do with R2 in the way?

Comment: Apply voltage division rule.

Comment: You forgot a minus sign in your op amp formula.

Comment: Since we know that the opamp will force a certain voltage at it's output we know what voltage is present at the left side of R2. That means we can replace the opamp with a voltage source. Then how is R2 and RL any different from a standard voltage divider?

Comment: You have an op-amp amplifier circuit and a potential divider circuit - separate things operating almost independently but joined together. Looking at it like that, take the next step and substitute the op-amp equation into the divider's equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, we are trying to analyze the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fC05Ui.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Using KCL, we can write:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_{\text{R}_1}+\text{I}_{\text{R}_2}=0\\
\\
\text{I}_\text{op}=\text{I}_{\text{R}_2}+\text{I}_{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_{\text{R}_3}=\text{I}_{\text{R}_4}
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

Using KVL, we can write:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_{\text{R}_1}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{in}-\text{V}_-}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_{\text{R}_2}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{op}-\text{V}_-}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_{\text{R}_3}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{op}-\text{V}_\text{out}}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_{\text{R}_4}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{out}}{\text{R}_4}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

Substituting \$(2)\$ into \$(1)\$, gives:

$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{\text{V}_\text{in}-\text{V}_-}{\text{R}_1}+\frac{\text{V}_\text{op}-\text{V}_-}{\text{R}_2}=0\\
\\
\text{I}_\text{op}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{op}-\text{V}_-}{\text{R}_2}+\frac{\text{V}_\text{op}-\text{V}_\text{out}}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_\text{op}-\text{V}_\text{out}}{\text{R}_3}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{out}}{\text{R}_4}
\end{cases}\tag3
$$

Using the fact that, in an ideal opamp:

$$\text{V}_-=\text{V}_+=0\tag4$$

Solving for the unknows gives:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{V}_\text{op}=-\frac{\text{R}_2}{\text{R}_1}\cdot\text{V}_\text{in}\\
\\
\text{I}_\text{op}=-\frac{\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4}{\text{R}_1\left(\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4\right)}\cdot\text{V}_\text{in}\\
\\
\text{V}_\text{out}=-\frac{\text{R}_2\text{R}_4}{\text{R}_1\left(\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4\right)}\cdot\text{V}_\text{in}
\end{cases}\tag5
$$

---

Let's suppose that \$x:=\text{R}_1=\text{R}_2=\text{R}_3=\text{R}_4\$, then equation \$(5)\$ simplifies to:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{V}_\text{op}=-\text{V}_\text{in}\\
\\
\text{I}_\text{op}=-\frac{3}{2x}\cdot\text{V}_\text{in}\\
\\
\text{V}_\text{out}=-\frac{1}{2}\cdot\text{V}_\text{in}
\end{cases}\tag6
$$

Answer (score 0):

I think what is confusing you is that you have used \$V_{OUT}\$ two different ways. Your formula for op amp gain assumes that \$V_{OUT}\$ is the actual output pin of the op amp, which is on the left side of R2. However, the schematic has arbitrarily labeled the right side of R2 as \$V_{OUT}\$.

There's nothing magic about the name \$V_{OUT}\$. Suppose we labeled the voltage across RL as \$V_L\$, and the voltage at the left side of R2 as \$V_{OUT}\$. Could you solve the problem now?

Answer (score -1):

RL and R2 are simply a resistor divider, the equation is:

\$ V_{out} = \frac{R_2}{R_2+R_L}V_{opamp output}\$